# Use of "extremely rarely"

Tags: grammar, word-usage

Is the use of "extremely rarely" grammatically correct? (To use In place of "very rarely")

Comment: Hi DC, and welcome to the EL&U stack! I find your question intriguing and look forward to seeing what comes of it. One tip I'd give about asking questions here, though, to avoid your Q from being tossed aside: the authorities here uphold the guidelines that can be found here: [Asking](https://english.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask). Maybe give a little background on what you _have_ found out about your Q before coming here?

Comment: Please explain why you think that it might not be. If some event is rare, snowstorms in midsummer, for example, you might say that snowstorms occur very rarely in midsummer. If some event is a once in a century phenomenon it is extremely rare, so there would be nothing wrong with say that it occurs extremely rarely.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, **extremely rarely** is grammatical.  As used in this sentence from the [OED](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/156496?rskey=eptFOc&result=2#eid115027675):

> 1994   K. E. Nye & J. M. Parkin HIV & AIDS    As is the case for many
>   infections with HIV, toxoplasmosis is due to a reactivation of
>   previously quiescent disease, and only **extremely rarely** a result of a
>   new infection.

and

> 2005   Language 8   While group genitives are **extremely rarely**
>   attested in written language, they can be found in spoken,
>   particularly colloquial, language.

Answer (score 0):

Grammatically it's correct. Both very and extremely are verbs of degree/intensity, which means they come before a word to emphasize the intensity of the phrase.

Ex:

- The test was extremely difficult
- The test was very difficult

**Both are correct, what's the difference then?**

It's the intensity, extremely represents more intensity than very, so it's correct, but one should not substitute another. In the sentence I wrote before, with extremely it gives the notion that the test was more difficult than in the second one.

In the context you gave, using extremely would emphasise that the event has less chances to occur than with very.

Comment: Yes, I was wandering about it as well, in my sense for example pretty would be higher than very. I only used it to make a clarification about extremely - very. Though I understand it can leads to disagreements so I'm gonna edit; thank you !